# Dealing with JSON in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have this JSON data

```
{  
   "siteInfo":{  
      "siteName":"Name",
      "logo":"Some String",
      "snappchat":"Some String",
      "whatsapp":"Some String",
      "twitter":"Some String",
      "groupName":"Some String"
   },
   "Apps":[  
      {  
         "category":Some String,
         "app_name":"Some String",
         "description":"Some String",
         "version":"Some String",
         "icon":"Some String",
         "download_counter":0,
         "appUrl":"Some String",
         "size":"Some String"
      },
      {  
         "category":Some String,
         "app_name":"Some String",
         "description":"Some String",
         "version":"Some String",
         "icon":"Some String",
         "download_counter":0,
         "appUrl":"Some String",
         "size":"Some String"
      }
    ],
   "notes":null
}
```

I download it using this code:

```
var app = [Apps]()

func DownloadFromStore(url:String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return
            }

            do {
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
                print(jsonResponse)

                print("hi?")
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                    return
                }
                print(jsonArray)

                for dic in jsonArray {
                    guard let title = dic["Apps"] as? String else { return }
                    print(title)  // Output
                }
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This is my struct:

```
class API : Codable {
    let siteInfo : siteInfo?
    let Apps : [Apps]?
    let notes : String?
    init(Apps: [Apps] ,siteInfo: siteInfo , notes : String)
    {
      self.Apps = Apps
      self.siteInfo = siteInfo
      self.notes = notes
    }
}

class siteInfo : Codable
{
    let siteName : String?
    let logo : String?
    let snappchat : String?
    let whatsapp : String?
    let twitter : String?
    let groupName : String?

    init(siteName : String , logo:String , snappchat :String , whatsapp: String, twitter :String ,groupName:String)
    {
        self.siteName = siteName
        self.logo = logo
        self.snappchat = snappchat
        self.whatsapp = whatsapp
        self.twitter = twitter
        self.groupName = groupName
    }
}

class Apps: Codable {
    let appUrl : String
    let app_name : String
    let category :String
    let description : String
    let download_counter : Int
    let icon : String
    let size : String
    let version : String

    init(appUrl : String ,app_name : String , category : String , description : String ,download_counter : Int , icon :String , size : String, version : String )
    {
        self.appUrl = appUrl
        self.app_name = app_name
        self.category = category
        self.description = description
        self.download_counter = download_counter
        self.icon = icon
        self.size = size
        self.version = version
    }
}
```

Here my collectionView code:

```
let Applists = [Apps]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : HomeCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let appfinal = Applists[indexPath.row]

    cell.appnamelabel.text = appfinal.app_name

    cell.appsizelabel.text = appfinal.size
    cell.appverlabel.text =  appfinal.version
    cell.SetImage(url: appfinal.icon ?? "")

    return cell
}
```

Why when is value of `Applists.count` is 0 and nothing inside my array?

The collectionView is empty too.

But when I print in func `Download()` it's giving me everything I want and it's perfect.

Every code is inside different file.

Comment: You are missing the fact that's the web call is asynchrone. And you don't reload your collectionView when it's downloaded.

Comment: What do u mean with  “ web call is asynchrone” ?

Comment: The block in `(data, response, error) in` will only run once the HTTP request has been completed.

Comment: Just after the `DownloadFromStore()` call, print something. Is "hi" supposed to be printed before or after it in your opinion?

Comment: Where is the relationship between the data source array and `DownloadFromStore`. In the code there is none. And don't **`sync`** dispatch queues in this case. Dispatch the queue ***async**hronously*.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the collection view data when you complete of creating models in API response.